# Argument of type Event is not assignable to parameter of type PanGestureEventData

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

I'm building an NativeScript app using angular flavor. In the HTML side I've tried to bind to an TouchEvent but this is the error that I've got.
Error message:

```
Argument of type 'Event' is not assignable to parameter of type 'PanGestureEventData'.
  Type 'Event' is missing the following properties from type 'PanGestureEventData': deltaX, deltaY, state, view, and 4 more.ngtsc(2345)
```

component.html

```
<Label
  class="content-drawer"
  (pan)="onPanMoveContainer($event)"
  alignSelf="center"
  textAlignment="center"
  [text]="'fa-window-minimize' | fonticon"
  class="fa"
  fontSize="20"
></Label>
```

component.ts

```
import { AfterViewInit, ChangeDetectorRef, Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { BottomSheetLayoutBaseComponent } from '@loyaltyversion2/xplat/features';
import { PanState } from '@loyaltyversion2/xplat/nativescript/utils';
import { PanGestureEventData, View } from '@nativescript/core';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'app-bottom-sheet-layout',
  templateUrl: './bottom-sheet-layout.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./bottom-sheet-layout.scss'],
})
export class BottomSheetLayoutComponent
  extends BottomSheetLayoutBaseComponent
{
  private currentContentTransitionY = 200;

  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  onPanMoveContainer(event: PanGestureEventData) {
    // TODO: why can't we use TouchGestureEventData

    this.moveContentToLocation(this.currentContentTransitionY + event.deltaY);

    if (event.state === PanState.UP) {
      this.currentContentTransitionY =
        this.currentContentTransitionY + event.deltaY;
    }
  }
}
```

My workspace is generated using nx/xplat@^12.0.0 and my guess is that there should be some misconfiguration regarding my tsconfig or some linters that are setup by xplat app generator but I didn't change anything in those files. Any guesses?

Comment: The `TouchGestureEventData` is for the `touch` event, not `pan`. if you update your HTML with `(touch)="onTouchMoveContainer($event)"`, it should let you use the `TouchGestureEventData`.

Comment: @William Juan In html im using pan the name of the method is touch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to disable 'strictTemplates' option in 'compilerOptions' located in your 'tsconfig.js'

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that there is a mixup between the event name and the function's expected parameter type.

If you want to use the `pan` event with the `PanGestureEventData`:

```html
<Label
  (pan)="onPanMoveContainer($event)"
></Label>
```

```js
onPanMoveContainer(event: PanGestureEventData) {
}
```

If you want to use the `touch` event with the `TouchGestureEventData`:

```html
<Label
  (touch)="onTouchMoveContainer($event)"
></Label>
```

```js
onTouchMoveContainer(event: TouchGestureEventData) {
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes the datatypes of events in the html and my backcode (component.ts) file are the same and both correspond to PanGestureEventData that's the function name which is onTouch which doesn't matter(as it's shown in my code that I've posted in the question).